# Spring @WebFilter causes 404 on prod, runs fine on local

Tags: spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, servlet-filters, url-pattern

I am using a @WebFilter with urlMapping = "/*" option. (Also tried with servlet). I use it to manage my oAuth single sign ons. It runs fine on local with tomcat on eclipse.

On prod it throws a 404. Disabling the filter(thus, by passing the filter) works fine.

Any pointers anyone?

AppConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.my.package")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements AsyncConfigurer {

    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        viewResolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver() {
      ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
      List<ViewResolver> viewResolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();
      viewResolvers.add(viewResolver());
      resolver.setViewResolvers(viewResolvers);
      return resolver;
}
```

AppInitializer.java:

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        //container.addFilter("name", AccessFilter.class);//Have tried toggling this

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        //configuration mapping
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);


        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");

    }

}
```

MyFilter.java:

```
//@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*") //Commenting this out works fine. Problem is surely with the filter.
public class AccessFilter implements Filter {
    SSOHelper ssoHelper;

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        //init the helper and internal property objects
        System.out.println("Filter init for dispatcher servlet");
        ssoHelper = new SSOHelper();
    }
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

//This is never hit when applied on prod. Local runs as expected. 
}
```